# Selenium webdriver will not fully load page (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using the selenium webdriver with python in an attempt to try and login to this website [Login Page Here](https://app.chatra.io/)

To do this I did the following in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import bs4 as bs


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://app.chatra.io/')
```

I then go on to make an attempt at parsing using Beautiful Soup:

```
html = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)
```

The main issue is that the page never fully loads. When I load the page in a browser on my own, all is fine. However when the selenium webdriver tries to load it, it just seemingly stops halfway.

Any idea why? Any ideas on how to fix it or where to look to learn?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the issue is also reproducible for me in the latest Chrome (with `chromedriver` 2.34 - also currently latest) - not yet sure what's happening at the moment. Workaround: *Firefox worked for me perfectly*.

---

And, I would add an extra step in between `driver.get()` and HTML parsing - an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to let the page properly load until the desired condition would be true:

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://app.chatra.io/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "signin-email")))

html = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Note that you also needed to call `prettify()` - it's a method.

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects to the issue you are facing as below :

- As you are trying to take help of **`BeautifulSoup`** so if you try to use **urlopen** from **urllib.request** the error says it all :

  ```
  urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
  ```

  Which means **urllib.request** is getting detected and **`HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`** is raised. Hence using **`webdriver`** from **`selenium`** makes sense.
- Next, when you take help of **`ChromeDriver`** and **`Chrome`** initially the `Website` opens and renders. But soon **`ChromeDriver`** being a **`WebDriver`** is detected and `ChromeDriver` is unable to parse the `<head>` & `<body>` tags. You see the minimal header as :

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="supports cssfilters flexwrap chrome webkit win hover web"></html>
  ```
- Finally, when you take help of **`GeckoDriver`** and **`Firefox Quantum`** the `Website` opens and renders properly as follows :

  Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://app.chatra.io/')
  html = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
  pagesoup = soup(html, "html.parser")
  print(pagesoup)
  ```

  Console Output :

  ```
  <html class="supports cssfilters flexwrap firefox gecko win hover web"><head>
  <link class="" href="https://app.chatra.io/b281cc6b75916e26b334b5a05913e3eb18fd3a4d.css?meteor_css_resource=true&amp;_g_app_v_=51" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
  .
  .
  .
  <em>··· Chatra</em>
  .
  .
  .
  </div></body></html>
  ```
- Adding **prettify** to the **soup** extraction :

  Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://app.chatra.io/')
  html = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
  pagesoup = soup(html, "html.parser")
  print(pagesoup.prettify)
  ```

  Console Output :

  ```
  <bound method Tag.prettify of <html class="supports cssfilters flexwrap firefox gecko win hover web"><head>
  <link class="" href="https://app.chatra.io/b281cc6b75916e26b334b5a05913e3eb18fd3a4d.css?meteor_css_resource=true&amp;_g_app_v_=51" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
  .
  .
  .
  <em>··· Chatra</em>
  .
  .
  .
  </div></body></html>>
  ```
- Even you can use `Selenium`'s **page_source** method as follows :

  Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://app.chatra.io/')
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```

  Console Output :

```html
<html class="supports cssfilters flexwrap firefox gecko win hover web">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="" href="https://app.chatra.io/b281cc6b75916e26b334b5a05913e3eb18fd3a4d.css?meteor_css_resource=true&amp;_g_app_v_=51">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">

  <!-- platform specific stuff -->
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <!-- favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">

  <!-- win8 tile -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/static/win-tile.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="application-name" content="Chatra">

  <!-- apple touch icon -->
  <!--<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="/static/?????.png">-->

  <title>··· Chatra</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background: #f6f5f7
    }
  </style>

  <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>



  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/meteor_runtime_config.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.chatra.io/9153feecdc706adbf2c71253473a6aa62c803e45.js?meteor_js_resource=true&amp;_g_app_v_=51"></script>



  <div class="body body-layout">
    <div class="body-layout__main main-layout">
      <aside class="main-layout__left-sidebar">
        <div class="left-sidebar-layout">
        </div>
      </aside>
      <div class="main-layout__content">
        <div class="content-layout">


          <main class="content-layout__main is-no-fades js-popover-boundry js-main">

            <div class="center loading loading--light">
              <div class="content-padding nothing">


                <em>··· Chatra</em>


              </div>
            </div>

          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```